# How to generate unique sequenceId for your application across multiple instances in KafkaStreams?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to generate the unique ordered Id for what we are consuming from the topic, And it should be unique around multiple instances. (Not uuid)

Comment: Why do you need this unique sequenceId?

Comment: To know the order of messages consumed by instances and add some more messages  between then and send to a different topic

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't wan to use a UUID. But you could use a combination of offset and partition number to compute a unique ID. Something like:

```java
// you need to know upfront how many partitions the input topis has
private final static int NUMBER_OF_PARTITIONS = ...

// within `Transformer#transform()` using `KStream#transform()`
// (also consider to use #transformValues() instead).

// `context` is given via `init()`

long id = context.offset() * NUMBER_OF_PARTITIONS + context.partition();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have written a LinkedIn article on this -
https://www.linkedin.com/posts/venkatesh-wagh_recently-had-encountered-a-problem-of-generating-activity-7111778200283676672-Dcm3?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_android

To generate a sequence - you can use offset or you can use incremental counter based on Kafka statestore

@matthias @onecricketer would be happy if you can have a review of this